# prove Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

I have a problem in this exercise

Suppose that ${(a_n)}$ is a sequence such that ${a_{2n}}$ ${}\le{}{}$ ${a_{2n+2}}$ ${}\le{}{}$  ${a_{2n+3}}$ ${}\le{}{}$ ${a_{2n+1}}$ for all n ${}\geq{}{}$ 0.

Show that this sequence is Cauchy iff  $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n-a_{n+1}|=0.$

Please suggest me for my work.
Thank you very much.

Comment: where are you stuck? can you prove one direction?

Comment: yes, thanks for told me. I don't known how to start this prove because there are not a constant fore example a1=1 a2=3 as a simple problems. please guide the step for prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence then it's convergent so $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n-a_{n+1}|=0$.
- Conversely, with the hypothesis we have the two sequences $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$ are adjacent so they are convergent sequences to the same limit so by a simple using of the definition we can prove that  $(a_n)$ is convergent then it's a cauchy sequence.

Comment: Oh... I see. First. It's use only definition of Cauchy? Now,I'm try to understand the next.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: excuse me. I don't known the reason that (an) is convergent then it's a Cauchy sequence. Why? please explain for this.

Comment: Is it come from completeness theorem?- A sequence of real number converges iff it is a cauchy sequence.

Comment: Yes that's right.